# JavaScript - Calculating the percentage of each index in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am attempting to calculate the percentage of an array that will have my total result equal 100%.

```
let dataArr = [  10232 , 23212,  98321, 32909, 29121, 20123 ]
```

I am starting off by calculating the total sum of the array.

here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vy2s41Lw/)

```
let dataArr = [  10232 , 23212,  98321, 32909, 29121, 20123 ] 

let dataSum = 0

let finalSum = [] 
    for (let i = 0; i < dataArr .length; i++) {
            dataSum += dataArr[i]
        }
    
    // console.log  dataSum = 213918
```

the `dataSum` is returning the value I am expecting

within the same loop I am now attempting to divide each individual index of the array by datasum * 100 in order to calculate a percentage. for example,

```
index 0 -> ` 10232 / datasum * 100` = 4.8%
index 1 -> ` 23212 / datasum * 100` = 10.9%
```

.... so on and so forth throughout the entire array. and having all percentages add up to 100%

I am attempting to handle the logic within the same forloop that handles the dataSum but I have issues with coming up the javascript logic for it.

Here is my attempt:

```
 for (let i = 0; i < dataArr .length; i++) {
            dataSum += finalArr[i]
            finalsum = finalArr[i] / dataSum * 100
        }

//console log finalSum = [100, 69.4055734959933, 74.61844951238949, 19.984332681540497, 15.026703475321861, 9.40687553174581] having the values equaling more then 100%
```

My expected outcome is to return all values from the `dataArr` with a percentage for each index having a total of 100%

Comment: you are dividing by `dataSum` which changes in each iteration. You cannot calculate the percentage of each value in regards to the total, without knowing the total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot perform this in the same loop. You need to use separate loop after you have the total sum.

```js
let dataArr = [10232, 23212, 98321, 32909, 29121, 20123]

let dataSum = 0

for (let i = 0; i < dataArr.length; i++) {
  dataSum += dataArr[i]
}

const finalSum = dataArr.map(item => item * 100 / dataSum);
console.log(dataSum, "dataSum")
console.log(finalSum, "finaaaal")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that in that way, it'll better to use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) array methods like this

```js
let dataArr = [10232, 23212, 98321, 32909, 29121, 20123]

let sum = dataArr.reduce((acc, el) => acc += el)

const final = dataArr.map(el => {
  let res = el * 100 / sum
  //res = Math.round(res) //Uncomment this line to round results
  return res
});
console.log(sum) //213918 
console.log(final) //array of final results
```